# How to display Date in Highcharts tooltip or below the categories

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to highcharts and I want to display date according to the data I get from the Database. I want to show date either in the tooltip or below the categories. Right now categories is displaying name of days. If possible I want to display date of that day below the Day in categories.

```
<script>
    Highcharts.chart('column', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: <?= json_encode($day_names) ?>,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0.5
            }
        },
        colors: [
            '#1cc88a', '#4e73df', '#f6c23e', '#e74a3b'
        ],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: JSON.parse('<?= $processed_stars_data ?>')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Hamza Iftikhar, Could you provide me with your series structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js to get the values formatted, but
 Highcharts has it's own date formatting functionality 
 which would be more idiomatic with Highcharts. It can be attached 
 onto the tooltip option in the highcharts constructor like so:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',
                                      new Date(this.x))
            + ' date, ' + this.y + ' Kg.';
        }
    }
```

You may want to also add the dateTimeLabelFormats object with the
 options you need for your dates, under the xAxis.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc23N/3/